# Mark Asset option not available

Tags: asset, asset-browser

Edit: In Blender 3.0 Alpha

There is no option to mark objects as assets. I'm not sure if the option is moved somewhere else or I missed tracking the alpha releases

[image]releases.

Comment: This is the 3.0 Alpha. I didn't include this in the question‍♂️

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you're looking for has been partially hidden for the average user. Blender has recently gained a system where beta features can be enabled / disabled by the user in the `Preferences`.

Open the Preferences by going to <kbd>Edit -> Preferences</kbd>, open the <kbd>Experimental</kbd> section and enable the **Extended Asset Browser**:

[image: Extended Asset Browser]

Then you should see the <kbd>Mark as Asset</kbd> and <kbd>Clear Asset</kbd> actions again in the context menu in the Outliner:

[image: Mark as Asset]

Comment: Also a sneaky spot for  "experimental" addon UI, far from the madding crowd, of addons tab.

Comment: In latest build after resetting to factory defaults there is neither Mark as Assets nor Experimental.

Comment: @Zingam It's there for me in my build, compiled two days ago. Are you still having this problem?

Comment: @aliasguru Thank you for answering me and sorry for wasting your time. As I had to reset my settings I completely forgot that to show the Experimental options for me to enable Create Asset, etc. I also needed to enable Developer Extras and the docs are a bit sketchy. To sum it up: 1. Blender Preferences -> Interface -> enable Developer Extras, 2. enable Experimental ->  Extended Asset Browser